# Fundamental misunderstanding of windowing

Tags: image-processing, filters, window

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of windowing. I thought that windowing is applied to a signal with pointwise multiplication, then some sort of filtering is then done to it (say using convolution in the time domain). However, looking back at my previous assignment, I seem to have applied the window to the filter itself(might be remembering incorrectly), which effectively means I convolved the signal with the window? Also, for images, it seems that I need to apply the window to a 2d kernel and not the image itself. This kernel then gets convolved with the image which means that I am once again convolving the image with the window, instead of pointwise multiplying. I understand that windowing is done to prevent spectral leakage/aliasing, but I dont quite get why it is being applied to the filter than the image itself.

If anyone could correct my misunderstanding I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of **windowing** a 2D image filter kernel, fits into a discrete-time FIR filter design method. Hence I will assume you are mixing windowing as a filter design method vs windowing applied to signals for Short-Time Fourier analysis or windowing applied for block-based processing of long signals. So please make it clear which action you are performing and the context of your intentions.

Then let me briefly describe windowing as a filter design tool.

An **ideal** discrete-time frequency selective LTI filter will have an infinite length and noncausal impulse response $h_i[n]$. So it shall be **truncated** and delayed for any practical FIR convolution applications.

Given an ideal filter impulse response $h_i[n]$, you obtain the coefficients of the practical impulse response $h[n]$ of length N samples via

$$h[n] = w[n] h_i[n]$$

Which is the point wise multiplication of the filter $h_i[n]$ with a window sequence $w[n]$ of length N. The main purposes of the window is to first truncate the infinite length ideal impulse response, and then to try to cure the side effects on the resulting filter spectrum caused by the crude truncation.

There are many different types of windows such as *box-car*,*triangular*, *Hamming*, *Hanning*, *Blackman*, *Kaiser*. The box-car is the crude rectangular window without any tapering. Other windows perform varying degrees of tapering at the ends of the impulse response so as to achieve a tradeoff between filter transition bandwith and passpand / stopband peak ripples.

Note that the windows's frequency response $W(e^{j\omega})$ is convolved with the ideal filter frequency response $H_i(e^{j\omega})$ which yields the frequency response of the practical filter;i.e,

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} H_i(e^{j\omega}) \star W(e^{j\omega}) $$.

Comment: robert, fat32: both of your explanations were great. but, I have a dumb question. your answers I think imply that windowing is always done in the time domain. is that correct ? I thought I heard of windowing in the frequency domain which confuses me, even though I understand it in the time domain. thanks.

Comment: @markleeds Many popular window functions, if centered at time zero, are weighted sums of a few cosines. If the length of such a window matches the length of a discrete Fourier transform carried out on a piece of the signal to be windowed, in such a way that the frequencies of the cosines match frequencies of the discrete frequency domain, then the cosine terms have simple frequency domain representations and time domain windowing can be implemented as convolution in the frequency domain by a filter of only a few taps.

Comment: @markleeds Hi mark! Just as (linear) independence vs (statistical) independence, the term **windowing** can also have different meanings in different contexts... As a filter design method, it has the meaning as in my answer. As a Short-Time FT tool it has a meaning like in RBJ's answer. **However** be careful to distinguish between, **action** (windowing as multiplication) in time domain and its **effect** (as convolution)  in frequency domain due to $$x[n]w[n] \leftrightarrow X(w) \star W(w). $$ Note that multiplication in frequency domain is typically called **masking** or weighting instead.

Comment: @markleeds Furthermore note that multiplication in frequency domain also equals convolution in time domain. So when you multiply (**action**) the DTFT $X(w)$  with window signal $W(w)$ in frequency domain, then **effectively** you are **convolving** (filtering) their time domain sequences as $$x[n] \star w[n] \leftrightarrow X(w)W(w)$$ indicates. So methematical expression is clear, but the intention and context must also be made clear to achieve the same meaning in both parties...

Comment: i would still use "$\omega$" instead of "$w$" for angular frequency, especially when there is a window function around called "$w[\cdot]$".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes I saw the possible confusion later, I knew you would see that :-) but \omega takes too long and 7x more characters especially when repeated in a comment... Hope it doesn't cause confusion for people though it would cause a definite confusion for a compiler !

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied to my question. My DSP knowledge is pretty thin so I will print it all out and try to absorb it all over this week.  All of the comments-explanations are much appreciated. This dsp.stackexchange community is an amazing group to learn from. All the best.

Comment: @markleeds Hi again! I don't know if I said it before but for a beginner's best route on Analog and Digital Signal Processing, I suggest you firmly read at least one *Signals and Systems* book. It can be from Haykin, Lathi or Opp. Try finding a solutions manual (may contain errors!); as solving end of chapter problems is a **must**... Try making Matlab/Octave implementations as well. And then come here for those concepts and questions that remain unclear to you :-)

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Yes I was understanding 'windowing' as some sort of universal operator, I didn't even think that they would be two different things when applied to different things (i.e signal preprocessing for stft and fir design). Thanks to you both!

Comment: @Fat32: No, you didn't so that's great advice. I'm putting that on to-do list but I'm working on my own project at the moment ( not DSP but uses some basic DSP priinciples ) so that endeavor may take a good while.  and I have oppenheimer which is a  good thing. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the window is of finite length, the application of a sliding window (a window re-applied every new sample to the most current $N$ samples) is the same as an FIR filter.  the window sample values, $w[n]$, are the same as the tap values or the Finite Impulse Response of an FIR filter.

now maybe you might be referring to the reciprocal fact that windowing in one domain (*time* or *frequency*) corresponds to convolution in the other reciprocal domain.  is that it?

Comment: Sorry, I did a bit more research and I think I know what I need to understand before I clear up this misunderstanding. First of all, I understand that there is this idea of spectral leakage when applying fft to a signal received from the time domain. This is because when the signal is passed through the fft, an inherently aperiodic signal is stitched together which forms discontinuities at the edges of the signal, which result in high frequencies appearing in the frequency spectrum.

Comment: So my first question is why is windowing necessary when designing FIR filters? I read that windowing 1. Truncates the filter to a finite resolution (an ideal box filter in the frequency domain is transformed into a sinc in the time domain with infinite resolution. Applying a window now gives it finite resolution.) 2. Reduces the gibbs phenomena. Wait, after typing that out it seems like windowing is applied in the time domain to the filter and not to the signal itself? Is that right?

Comment: your first comment is exactly correct, the FFT is just an efficient method of the DFT, and the DFT **always** periodically extends the $N$ samples of data passed to it.  the DFT thinks those $N$ samples are one cycle of a periodic waveform that repeats every $N$ samples. this is that *"stiching together"* you refer to.  but there is an equivalent way of looking at the DFT in that your $N$ samples are zero-extended, we apply the DTFT, which evaluates $H(z)$ on the unit circle ($z=e^{j\omega}$) and the DFT samples that unit circle at $N$ equally-spaced points.

Comment: windowing is not **always** necessary to design FIR filters.  *Parks-McClellan*  (`firpm()`) and *Weighted Least-Squares* (`firls()`) are two methods of designing FIR filters that are not the *Windowing Method*.  the windowing method is 1. Draw out the desired frequency response. 2. applying Hermitian symmetry, inverse FFT to get the Impulse Response.  3. shorten the Impulse response to the finite length of the FIR.  windowing is what happens when you shorten the impulse response to the length $L$ that you can pay for.

Comment: i think your questions should be migrated to your question and my answers should be migrated to the answer.